# TinyMCE - use browser context menu to initiate a paste

Tags: html, tinymce, text-editor

I am using TinyMCE editor and I have run into a problem. I need to use the right click and paste function. However it seems that with tinyMCE 5 having context menu within the core itself the only way is to use the shortcut.

Is there anyway to use paste functionality using the right mouse click. I think it should work if i was able to somehow disable context menu. but I am not sure how to do it since its now embedded in the core in TinyMCE 5

```
selector:'textarea',
plugins: "code,autosave,wordcount,advlist,lists,link,paste,fullscreen,table,emoticons",
contextmenu: "link cut copy paste",
toolbar: " bold italic strikethrough link blockquote emoticons | restoredraft | paste numlist bullist outdent indent | table | fullscreen ",
forced_root_block : "",
```

Comment: What this has to do with PHP or arrays?

Comment: @dWinder I have edited the question to remove those tags.

Answer (score 2):

If you <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + Right Click in the editor it will bypass the context menu and show the browser's context menu instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using `contextmenu: false` disables the TinyMCE context menu and shows the system one, which allows cut/copy/paste features.